# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, jboss, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jndi

I am running an example of ejb using JBoss5 Container. I am using an example 
[from here(Part one)](http://www.roseindia.net/jboss/jboss_3.2.shtml).

In the example I deployed bean in JBoss and an application in Tomcat(to acces the bean from JBoss). I am getting the error in the screen of tomcat server 
**javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: greetJndi not bound**

( greetJndi is the jndi-name in jboss.xml file )
Is there any specific directory structure to deploy in JBoss?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> I am getting the error (...) javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: greetJndi not bound

This means that nothing is bound to the jndi name `greetJndi`, very likely because of a deployment problem given the **incredibly low quality** of this tutorial (check the server logs). I'll come back on this.

> Is there any specific directory structure to deploy in JBoss?

The internal structure of the `ejb-jar` is supposed to be like this (using the **poor naming conventions and the default package** as in the mentioned link):

```
.
├── greetBean.java
├── greetHome.java
├── greetRemote.java
└── META-INF
    ├── ejb-jar.xml
    └── jboss.xml
```

But as already mentioned, this tutorial is full of mistakes:

- there is an extra character  (`<enterprise-beans>]` <-- HERE) in the `ejb-jar.xml` (!)
- a space is missing after `PUBLIC` in the `ejb-jar.xml` and `jboss.xml` (!!)
- the `jboss.xml` is incorrect, it should contain a `session` element instead of `entity` (!!!)

Here is a "fixed" version of the `ejb-jar.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Enterprise JavaBeans 2.0//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/ejb-jar_2_0.dtd">
<ejb-jar>
  <enterprise-beans>
    <session>
      <ejb-name>greetBean</ejb-name>
      <home>greetHome</home>
      <remote>greetRemote</remote>
      <ejb-class>greetBean</ejb-class>
      <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
      <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
    </session>
  </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

And of the `jboss.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD JBOSS 3.2//EN" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss_3_2.dtd">
<jboss>
  <enterprise-beans>
    <session>
      <ejb-name>greetBean</ejb-name>
      <jndi-name>greetJndi</jndi-name>
    </session>
  </enterprise-beans>
</jboss>
```

After doing these changes and repackaging the ejb-jar, I was able to successfully deploy it:

```
21:48:06,512 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@5060868{vfszip:/home/pascal/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/greet.jar/}
21:48:06,534 INFO  [EjbDeployer] installing bean: ejb/#greetBean,uid19981448
21:48:06,534 INFO  [EjbDeployer]   with dependencies:
21:48:06,534 INFO  [EjbDeployer]   and supplies:
21:48:06,534 INFO  [EjbDeployer]    jndi:greetJndi
21:48:06,624 INFO  [EjbModule] Deploying greetBean
21:48:06,661 WARN  [EjbModule] EJB configured to bypass security. Please verify if this is intended. Bean=greetBean Deployment=vfszip:/home/pascal/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/greet.jar/
21:48:06,805 INFO  [ProxyFactory] Bound EJB Home 'greetBean' to jndi 'greetJndi'
```

That tutorial needs significant improvement; I'd advise from staying away from roseindia.net.

Comment: can you help with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996931/namenotfoundexception-when-running-simple-webapp-in-jboss-6-but-not-on-jboss-7

Answer (score 4):

The error means that your are trying to look up JNDI name, that is not attached to any EJB component - the component with that name does not exist.

As far as dir structure is concerned: you have to create a JAR file with EJB components. As I understand you want to play with EJB 2.X components (at least the linked example suggests that) so the structure of the JAR file should be:

/com/mypackage/MyEJB.class
/com/mypackage/MyEJBInterface.class
/com/mypackage/etc... etc... java classes
/META-INF/ejb-jar.xml
/META-INF/jboss.xml

The JAR file is more or less ZIP file with file extension changed from ZIP to JAR.

BTW. If you use JBoss 5, you can work with EJB 3.0, which are much more easier to configure. The simplest component is

```
@Stateless(mappedName="MyComponentName")
@Remote(MyEJBInterface.class)
public class MyEJB implements MyEJBInterface{
   public void bussinesMethod(){

   }
}
```

No ejb-jar.xml, jboss.xml is needed, just EJB JAR with MyEJB and MyEJBInterface compiled classes.

Now in your client code you need to lookup "MyComponentName".