# NameNotFoundException when running simple webapp in JBOSS 6 but Not on JBOSS 7

Tags: rest, jboss, jboss7.x, java-ee-6, jboss6.x

I have a simple web-app (`REST service and EJB`) that when I run on `JBOSS 7` works fine. But on `JBOSS 6` I get `NameNotFoundException`. I am unable to figure out why it works with `JBOSS 7` but not with `JBOSS 6`. my `pom.xml` includes dependencies for `java ee 6 api`. Here is the code:

**jax-rs activator:**

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
}
```

**EJB**

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class ServiceImpl {

    public Date getCurrentDate(){
        return new Date();
    }

}
```

**REST**

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Stateless
@Path("current")
public class ServiceFacade {

    @EJB
    ServiceImpl service;

    @GET
    public String getDate(){
        return service.getCurrentDate().toString();
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sample.rest</groupId>
  <artifactId>restejb</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <description>simplet project to test ejb injection in rest</description>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
            <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
</project>
```

when I access the following url, I get the below error

`http://localhost:8080/restejb/rest/current`

```
13:32:33,958 INFO  [AbstractServer] Starting: JBossAS [6.1.0.Final "Neo"]
    13:32:36,972 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.7.0_71,Oracle Corporation
    13:32:36,972 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
    13:32:36,973 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.71-b01,Oracle Corporation
    13:32:36,973 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Mac OS X 10.9.5,x86_64
    13:32:36,975 INFO  [ServerInfo] VM arguments: -Dprogram.name=JBossTools: JBoss AS 6.x -Xms256m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/sridhar1982AQ/Documents/EE7_servers/jboss-6.1.0.Final/lib/endorsed -Djava.library.path=/Users/sridhar1982AQ/Documents/EE7_servers/jboss-6.1.0.Final/bin/native -Dlogging.configuration=file:/Users/sridhar1982AQ/Documents/EE7_servers/jboss-6.1.0.Final/bin/logging.properties -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
    13:32:37,065 INFO  [JMXKernel] Legacy JMX core initialized
    ........

    13:33:11,130 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/restejb
    13:33:11,590 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class com.example.rest.RestApplication
    13:33:22,999 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] Unknown exception while executing GET /current: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: local not bound
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.JndiComponentResourceFactory.createResource(JndiComponentResourceFactory.java:57) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:208) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:496) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invokePropagateNotFound(SynchronousDispatcher.java:155) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:212) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:59) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [:1.7.0_71]
    Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: local not bound
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:771) [:5.0.5.Final]
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:779) [:5.0.5.Final]
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:785) [:5.0.5.Final]
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:443) [:5.0.5.Final]
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:399) [:5.0.5.Final]
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:728) [:5.0.5.Final]
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:688) [:5.0.5.Final]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) [:1.7.0_71]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.JndiComponentResourceFactory.createResource(JndiComponentResourceFactory.java:53) [:6.1.0.Final]
        ... 25 more

    13:33:23,013 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/restejb].[default]] Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: local not bound
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:241) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:190) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:534) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:496) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invokePropagateNotFound(SynchronousDispatcher.java:155) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:212) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:59) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [:1.7.0_71]
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: local not bound
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.JndiComponentResourceFactory.createResource(JndiComponentResourceFactory.java:57) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:208) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519) [:6.1.0.Final]
        ... 23 more
    Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: local not bound
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:771) [:5.0.5.Final]
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:779) [:5.0.5.Final]
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:785) [:5.0.5.Final]
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:443) [:5.0.5.Final]
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:399) [:5.0.5.Final]
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:728) [:5.0.5.Final]
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:688) [:5.0.5.Final]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) [:1.7.0_71]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.JndiComponentResourceFactory.createResource(JndiComponentResourceFactory.java:53) [:6.1.0.Final]
        ... 25 more
```

Comment: Are you deploying the ejb in a war file?

Comment: yes, all in war file. how did it work in Jboss 7 but not jboss 6? or how would I bundle just ejb in jar and deploy from eclipse?

Comment: Ok, first check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213174/jboss-6-deploy-ejb-in-war-packaging maybe can help you

Comment: I tried what is suggested in this post. but did not help

Comment: Why do you use the @Stateless annotation in your rest endpoint class?

Comment: If you want to inject ejb in rest, you have to have @Stateless in rest endpoint. please see these below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027834/inject-a-ejb-into-jax-rs-restfull-service